# Convergence of $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{\sin n}{n}$ and $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{\cos n}{n}$ without Dirichlet's test

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

I want to prove the convergence of

$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{\sin n}{n}\qquad\text{and}\qquad \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{\cos n}{n}$$

without using the Dirichlet test (since I have not covered it in class). 
What is an elementary way to do this? Solutions without complex numbers/Euler's formula are preferred if possible.

Comment: It's not easy and I am keen to see an answer that does it with standard tests. One problem is that inputs are supposed to be radians instead of degrees.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Let $S_N = \sum_{n=1}^{N} \frac{\sin n}{n}$. Then by utilizing a trigonometric identity,

\begin{align*}
S_N \sin 1
&= \sum_{n=1}^{N} \frac{\cos(n-1) - \cos(n+1)}{2n} \\
&= \frac{1}{2} + \frac{\cos 1}{4} - \frac{\cos N}{2N-2} - \frac{\cos(N+1)}{2N} - \sum_{n=2}^{N-1} \frac{\cos n}{n^2-1}.
\end{align*}

As $N\to\infty$, this clearly converges by the comparison test, and so, $S_N$ also converges. Similar argument also applies to $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{\cos n}{n}$.

Comment: This reminds me Abel’s summation formula.